# Filtering the output from Table and export it into excel

Tags: excel, inequalities

I have the following functions

```
f1[c1_,c2_,p1_,n_,i_]:= Sum[
    Binomial[n,j]  p1^j (1-p1)^(n-j),
        {j,0,c1}] + Sum[
    Binomial[n,k] p1^k (1-p1)^(n-k+n i),
        {k,c1+1,c2}]
```

and

```
f2[c1_,c2_,p2_,n_,i_]:=Sum[
    Binomial[n,j] p2^j (1-p2)^(n-j),
        {j,0,c1}] + Sum[
    Binomial[n,k] p2^k (1-p2)^(n-k+n i),
        {k,c1+1,c2}]
```

(actually the functions are identical. Both are kept for "historical" reasons) 
From the output of

```
Table[Table[Table[{f1[c1, c2, 0.01, n, 5], f2[c1, c2, 0.05, n, 5]}, {c2, 
    c1 + 1, 6, 1}], {c1, 0, 4, 1}], {n, 175, 185}]
```

I need only such values which satisfy $f_1\geq 0.95$ and $f_2\leq0.05$ with there parameters (value of $c_1$,$c_2$ and $n$). And how to export this output in excel.

Comment: @mikuszefski If you change $f_1$ and $f_2$ in 'Mathematica' code then it may be more useful. I am facing some issue's to do that.

Comment: Ok...I did thid as you mixed traditional and standard form. Will change it to plain code

Comment: Hi Ali, can you check your `f1` and `f2`. The first `p2^k` in `f2` does not make sense. Moreover, if I correct this to `p2^j`, I do not see any difference between `f1` and `f2`.

Comment: Is it that you used `=` instead of `:=` in your function definition that you couldn't just use `{..., f[..., 0.01, ...], f[..., 0.05, ...], ...}`?

Comment: @mikuszefski yes, I correct. Thanks

Comment: There's still a comma missing before the iterator at the end of the `f2` function.

Comment: Am I missing something or is `f1=f2`?

Comment: @mikuszefski almost equal, but $p_1$ and $p_2$ always have different values.

Comment: Sure, but that is a function call, so calling it `p1` or `p2` shouldn't matter. Did you try the version with `:=` instead of `=` and using only, e.g., `f1`?

Comment: @mikuszefski It may be, but I have no idea how to handle it and it will be useful for filtering the output as I needed.

Comment: No doubt that it works this way. Nevertheless, on defines a function exactly for this purpose, to be evaluated with different input parameters, whether this is `c1` or `p1` doesn't matter. You definitively do not define functions for all possible values of `c1`, right? Don't get me wrong, I am only asking as this might improve your understanding of *Mathematica* and how to use it efficiently.

Comment: I'll post an answer to make myself clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I think that one function definition is ok:

```
f[c1_,c2_,p_,n_,i_]:= Sum[
    Binomial[n,j]  p^j (1-p)^(n-j),
        {j,0,c1}] + Sum[
    Binomial[n,j] p^j (1-p)^(n-j+n i),
        {j,c1+1,c2}]
```

Then use the k_v's answer in the form

```
t=Flatten[
    Table[
        If[(a=f[c1, c2, 0.01, n, 5])≥0.95 && (b=f[c1, c2, 0.05, n, 5])≤0.05,
        {c1,c2,n,a,b}], 
    {c1, 0, 4, 1}, {c2, c1 + 1, 6, 1}, {n, 175, 185}
    ]/.Null->Sequence[]/.{}-> Sequence[],
2]
```

as it seems that you want to keep track of the input parameters as well. Flattening provides a single list of parameter-solution vectors, which one exports again as said by k_v using

```
Export["myFile.xls",t]
```

Comment: I am unable to find output from the above code.

Comment: Check with `Directory[]` to which directory *Mathematica* is writing by default. Look at the answer of zentient for setting a linux path. In Windows would be something like `Export["C:\\users\\YOURUSERNAME\\Desktop\myFile.xls",t]`. Change "YOURUSERNAME" by your real user name. And note that "users" may be different as well, if you are not using an english operating system (in Spanish, e.g., it is Usuarios, in German Benutzer, etc.). Also note the double backslash required to provide the system required bqckslash from a *Mathematica* string.

Comment: I got the excel file but empty and in Mathematica output it is just { }. Thats the issue...

Comment: @Ali, looking at the answer from @zentient, it seems that there are no values in your given range. So if the both conditions `f1>0.95` and `f2<0.05` are never fulfilled at the same time, your list will be empty. Check the values produced by your functions and according parameters. Maybe a parameter value is incorrect?

Comment: @Ali Do you have a link to have a look at the origin of your `f`? That is a somewhat modified binomial distribution, but with `p<1` `1-p` with exponent `-n i` will grow very rapidly for `i=5` and `n=180`. Are you sure about the`(1-p)^(n-j-n*i)` or is it maybe only `(1-p)^(n-j-i)`?

Comment: Kindly run this code `f1[c1_, c2_, p1_, n_, 
   i_] = (Sum[Binomial[n, j] p1^j (1 - p1)^(n - j), {j, 0, c1}] + 
     Sum[Binomial[n, k] p1^k (1 - p1)^(n - k + n i), {k, c1 + 1, 
       c2}]) >= 0.95;
f2[c1_, c2_, p2_, n_, 
   i_] = (Sum[Binomial[n, l] p2^l (1 - p2)^(n - l), {l, 0, c1}] + 
     Sum[Binomial[n, m] p2^m (1 - p2)^(n - m + n i), {m, c1 + 1, 
       c2}]) <= 0.05;
Table[Table[
  Table[{f1[c1, c2, 0.01, n, 5], f2[c1, c2, 0.05, n, 5]}, {c2, c1 + 1,
     6, 1}], {c1, 0, 4, 1}], {n, 180, 185}]`. I get several {true,true} in output and all output between 0 and 1.

Comment: but same functions run in your and zentient way causes problem. So there is problem some where in the code. Because these are the probabilities.

Comment: @Ali Ok, got it, your original post had (1-p)^(n-j-n i), which-as I said-becomes quite large due to the negative exponent. The code you commented now has (1-p)^(n-j+n i), such that the exponent stays positive and the values way below 1. I'll edit my answer and the post accordingly. –  mikuszefski 12 mins ago

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a full [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) of values as you stated

```
myTable = Table[
  {c1, c2, n, f1[c1, c2, 0.01, n, 5], f2[c1, c2, 0.05, n, 5]}, 
  {c1, 0, 4, 1}, 
  {c2, c1 + 1, 6, 1},
  {n, 175, 185}
  ];
```

Then make a selection of the values you wish using [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) and [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

```
mySelection = Select[
  Partition[Flatten[myTable], 5], 
  #[[4]] >= 0.95 && #[[5]] <= 10^17 &
  ]
```

Note that I changed the bound for the `f2` function here as it seems to produce very different values than your original limits seemed to anticipate.

Finally [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) the result to Excel

```
Export["~/Desktop/mySelect.xlsx", mySelection]
```

You will have to change the path for your OS if it's not Unix-based.

Comment: I like the `Select[]` alternative but sort of prefer `Flatten[..., 2]` over `Partition[Flatten[ ], 5]`

Comment: @zentient $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the probabilities, so always lies between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

firs of all there's no need to use nested `Table`, and you may use values selection directly inside the table evaluation

```
t=Table[
If[f1[c1, c2, 0.01, n, 5]≥0.95 && f2[c1, c2, 0.05, n, 5]≤0.05,
{f1[c1, c2, 0.01, n, 5], f2[c1, c2, 0.05, n, 5]}], 
{c1, 0, 4, 1}, {c2, c1 + 1, 6, 1}, {n, 175, 185}]/.Null->Sequence[]/.{}-> Sequence[]
```

this way let not to brake the structure of output

to export - `Export["table.xls",t]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have huge interval of 'n' for specimen here I give small interval of 'n'. So in output I need parametric value's e.g 'c1','c2' and 'n' for each favourable output. Also usual 'Export' function is meaning less in that case.

Comment: Isn't *Mathematica* evaluating the `f`'s twice without necessity? Could one do something like `If[ ( (a=f1[...])>...) && ( (b=f2[...])<...),{a,b}]`, to be more efficient?

Comment: @mikuszefski I can't see any reason to define two similar functions too, but as far as they are used with different arguments unification doesn't matter for time-efficiency. `Compile` and `ParallelTable` would give best resoult on my opinion

Comment: I was not talking about `f1` vs `f2`, I meant that you first evaluate the specific set of parameters to check the condition, then evaluate the exact same set to put the result into the list.

Comment: @mikuszefski it's a good idea